# Is there a built in function (Java) for an Android app to get the date range of the week of the current date ("today")

Tags: java, android, date-range

I know this should be quite easy with Joda-Time, but I think it is not standard in Android Studio.

Say we are currently Wednesday October 12, then the start date of the current week (assuming it starts on Sunday) should be Sunday October 9, and the last day of the week should be Saturday October 15.

Are there any existing methods doing this?

-Thanks

Comment: Why can't you compile Joda into your app?

Comment: Please search Stack Overflow before posting.